# Spritekit game crashes when pausing scene from app delegate

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am attempting to pause the game when the user navigates away from the app or clicks on the ad using the following code:

```
 SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
    view.paused = YES;
```

This used to work in pausing the game, but due to some other stuff going on, I ended up adding another viewcontroller to handle the title scene, and got everything working, but for some reason the pause code now doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPaused:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170174280'
```

Note that I am still able to pause within my scene using

```
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Through reading some of the other related questions, I can see that it might be useful to use NSNotification? Another option is to add an observer? Does anyone know why the pause code I am using is not working from the appDelegate anymore and what I can do to fix this?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new method in appDelegate:

```
- (SKView *)getGameView {
    NSArray *viewControllers = self.window.rootViewController.childViewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {
        if ([vc.view isKindOfClass:[SKView class]]) {
            SKView *view = (SKView *)vc.view;
            return view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and now ... modify your code from:

```
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = YES;
```

to:

```
SKView *view = [self getGameView];
   if (view) {
       view.paused = YES; //or NO
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that either `rootViewController` is not the `ViewController`, which operates `SKView`, or `rootViewController.view` is not `SKView`.

Use `NSNotificationCenter` instead of trying to pause the game directly from `AppDelegate`:

```
@interface GameSceneViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SKView *skView;

@end

@implementation GameSceneViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pause) name:@"pauseView" object:nil];
}
- (void)pause {
    self.skView.pause = YES;
}

@end
```

And then just call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pauseView" object:nil];
```

Comment: I added this code, but it did not seem to work. I called that last line in the App Delegate under the 'applicationDidEnterBackground' method, and I still got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I navigated away from the app. I suspect there might be something going on besides the pause logic, but I have no idea what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code in AppDelegate:

- WillResignActive:

  ```
  -(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

      YourViewController *viewGame = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: StoryboardName bundle: nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: identifier];

      SKView *view = (SKView *)viewGame.view.window;
      view.paused = YES;

  }
  ```
- and in DidBecomeActive:

  ```
  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

  if (!self.window.rootViewController.view)  {
      YourViewController *viewGame = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: StoryboardName bundle: nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: identifier];

      SKView *view = (SKView *)viewGame.view.window;
      view.paused = NO;
     }
  }
  ```